# Ambiguous call when using LINQ extension method on DbSet<T>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ambiguous, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am using a LINQ query on a `DbSet<T>`:

```cs
await _dbContext.Users.AnyAsync(u => u.Name == name);
```

However, the compiler outputs the following error:

```
Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AnyAsync<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource, bool>)' and
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.AnyAsync<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource, bool>>)'
```

A similar problem also occurs with other LINQ extension methods, like `.Where()`.

I am using EF.Core 3.1 and have the `System.Linq.Async` package installed. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The described problem is caused by using the `System.Linq.Async` package along with the `DbSet<TEntity>` class.

Since `DbSet<TEntity>` implements both `IQueryable<TEntity>` and `IAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>`, importing the namespaces `System.Linq` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` leads to the definition of the conflicting extension methods. Unfortunately, avoiding importing one of them is usually not practicable.

This behavior is present beginning with EF.Core 3.0, and is discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18124).

In order to address this, EF.Core 3.1 adds two auxiliary functions `AsAsyncEnumerable()` and `AsQueryable()`, which explicitly return the respective interfaces `IAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>` or `IQueryable<TEntity>`.

The given code sample is fixed by calling the desired disambiguation function:

```cs
await _dbContext.Users.AsQueryable().AnyAsync(u => u.Name == name);
```

or

```cs
await _dbContext.Users.AsAsyncEnumerable().AnyAsync(u => u.Name == name);
```

Comment: Just wondering, is there difference (performance or otherwise) between the 2 workarounds that you showed?

Comment: @GregZ. The performance impact is no different from a regular C# cast: `AsQueryable()` and `AsAsyncEnumerable()` simply perform a cast to their respective interfaces. `AsQueryable()` just casts `this` to `(IQueryable<TEntity>) this`,  and `AsAsyncEnumerable()` casts `this` to `(IAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>)this`.