# What happens to the WHERE clause with IAsyncEnumerable in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, iasyncenumerable

I'm porting an existing application that uses Entity Framework with a SQL Server database from .NET Framework to .NET Core. In EF6, you could do:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetByExpressionAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where))
{
    return await _context.DbSet<T>().Where(where).ToListAsync();
}
```

Assuming that the `where` expression could be evaluated server-side, this would translate to a SQL query like `SELECT columns FROM table WHERE Foo=1`.

This is the same method in EF Core. Yes, I realize I'm not taking advantage of async streams, but remember this is an existing application and I don't have the time to really redesign it.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetByExpressionAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where))
{
    return await _context.DbSet<T>().AsAsyncEnumerable().Where(where.Compile()).ToListAsync();
}
```

The table that I'm having the problem with has hundreds of thousands of records. If I use SQL Profiler, I can see that there is no `WHERE` clause, so SQL Server is returning the entire table, which is of course so not ideal. I didn't notice at first because my unit tests run against a much smaller table so there was no indication there would be a performance issue.

According to [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works), "The database provider identifies which parts of the query can be evaluated in the database" and "These parts of the query are translated to database-specific query language". So when I use simple `[column] == [value]` filters, this should work properly, and indeed, the synchronous works exactly as expected.

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetByExpression(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where))
{
    return _context.DbSet<T>().AsQueryable().Where(where).ToList();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't do `AsAsyncEnumerable` with a where - that will be super greedy

Comment: @DanielA.White Yep, that's what I observed, but what am I supposed to do? I can't use `await _context.DbSet<T>().AsQueryable().Where(where).ToListAsync()` because I get "The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable" (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743165/toarrayasync-throws-the-source-iqueryable-doesnt-implement-iasyncenumerable)

Comment: Can you talk us through what happens if you use the EF6 code in EF Core? Does it work? If it does work, why are you unhappy with it?

Comment: @mjwills The EF6 code flat-out doesn't work in EF Core. It won't compile because of an AmbiguousMatchException (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60347952/ambiguous-call-when-using-linq-extension-method-on-dbsett), so you have to add `.AsQueryable()` and `.AsAsyncEnumerable()`.

Comment: @howcheng Then just add `AsQueryable()`after the `DbSet` accessor to resolve the ambiguous call, and keep the rest the same as in EF6, e.g. `return await _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().Where(where).ToListAsync();`

Comment: @IvanStoev OMG I swear I tried that already and it did nothing, but now it seems to work. WTF. Well, thanks for the pointer.